I need to route snmp commands out a specific ethernet port
I have Ubuntu Linux 22.04 that makes SNNP requests to get SNMP data from remote devices.
I have 2 ethernet ports eno1: 192.168.100.40 and eno2: 192.168.10.40. I would like all snmp commands like get,walk,etc. to only go out eno2:.  I have looked at IPtable etc.  Not really very familiar in this area.  Any help would be great. Thanks Much.

It's possible but quite tricky. Are you sure you can't use normal destination-based routing? Also, do you need to be able to run other traffic via eno2 interface with other routing? If not, you can assign it to a VRF which would have alternate default gateway and then run snmp commands in context of that VRF with ip vrf exec. If that's sufficient, I can explain it in more detail in an answer.

My problem is all the equipment is configured to only listen on 161 from 192.168.10.40 for SNMP requests.  I need the other port for ICMP and TCP traffic to the same devices. They are individually configured and their are 880 in use.   If I could somehow source all UDP traffic on the eno2: interface that would work as well.   We went to a new subnet and server and this complicated things for us..

VRF looks promising... I am looking into it now and trying to learn the commands.

Thank you this solved the problem.  I have used Cisco VRF and this was very similar in design.  Appreciate your help!

This is complicated with SNMP because net-snmp utilites don't have an option to bind to certain local IP address, rendering "usual" methods of source-based routing ineffective. So we need another approach.
Let's suppose the gateway behind eno1 is set as a default route in the main routing table. Let also suppose the gateway behind eno2 is 192.168.10.x.
Now you create VRF, assign eno2 to it and add a default route via its gateway into that VRF:
ip link add vrf-snmp type vrf table 10
ip link set dev vrf-snmp up
ip link set dev eno2 master vrf-snmp
ip addr add 192.168.10.40/24 dev eno2
ip route add default via 192.168.10.x table 10

Notice that I add route into the same table I associated VRF with.
Now, this VRF has alternate routing. Whenever you need to send traffic out via 192.168.10.x (through eno2), you need to run your program in context of that VRF:
ip vrf exec vrf-snmp snmpwalk -v2c ...

(or simply run a whole shell with ip vrf exec vrf-snmp bash to not need any additional prefix)
This is similar to having an additional network namespace and running your programs in that namespace (and that would work too), but in my opinion this approach is simpler to setup and use.
Further reading:

man ip-vrf
Linux Virtual Routing and Forwarding

